# Returning the list of list converted to an array, excluding any null items

Tags: java, arraylist, sub-array

Finding it difficult to return the list of list converted to an array, excluding any null items. Items should occur in the order they appear in the list. My test is passing until line:
assertEquals("[-1, -2, -1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 200, 700, 900, 10, 20, 90, 20, 22]", Arrays.toString(result)); I am wondering what the issue is.

```
public static int[] nonNullItemsToArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int arrayLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) != null) {
            arrayLength += list.get(i).size();
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    int[] alist = new int[arrayLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) != null) {
            for (int k = 0; k < list.get(i).size(); k++) {
                if (list.get(i).get(k) != null) {
                    alist[j++] = list.get(i).get(k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return alist;
}

@Test @Graded(description="NonNullItemsToArrayComprehensive")
    public void testNonNullItemsToArrayComprehensive() {
        testNonNullItemsToArrayBasic();
        int[] result = ListOfListService.nonNullItemsToArray(null);
        assertEquals(null, result);

        result = ListOfListService.nonNullItemsToArray(list4_nullItems);
        assertEquals("[-1, -2, -1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 200, 700, 900, 10, 20, 90, 20, 22]", Arrays.toString(result));
        currentMethodName = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
    }
```

Comment: Why/How is the test failing? (wrong result/exception) What is the input you are passing (contents of `list4_nullItems`)?

Comment: It is failing at this line assertEquals("[-1, -2, -1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 200, 700, 900, 10, 20, 90, 20, 22]", Arrays.toString(result));

Comment: What does your function return as a result?

Answer (score 1):

As saka already mentioned in [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67444781/7525132), your code produces unwanted `0` entries in the result array, specifically one `0` entry for each `null` entry in a nested list in the input.

```
input  = [[1, 2, null], null, [null, 3, 4]]
           entry 1 ^     entry 2 ^

output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
       in the result  ^  ^
```

The root cause for this is that you do not account for these nested `null` entries when calculating the initial array size.

```
int arrayLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) != null) {
        arrayLength += list.get(i).size();
    }
}
```

Here, instead of simply doing `arrayLength += list.get(i).size()` you have to determine the number of non-`null` entries in the nested list and add this count to `arrayLength`.

```
for (int k = 0; k < list.get(i).size(); k++) {
    if (list.get(i).get(k) != null) {
       arrayLength++;
    }
}
```